# Embedded google map - how to locate to a given coordinate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Is it possible to locate to a given coordinate in a embedded google map? I need to show predefined location when user clicks on a link or a button. I have a list of locations in a table with their coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to it, you need to add an event listener which will make the call to the map to recenter it.

If you check out the [Google Maps API - google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) there is a `panTo(latLng:LatLng)` method available which you could use by hitting a function of some sort (provided your initial `map` variable is globally defined. like so:

```
function mapPanTo(lat,long) {
    var newLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
    map.panTo(newLatLong);
}
```

and your call to action could be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="mapPanTo('-32.1100','115.9348'); return false;">
    change the map!
</a>
```

hope that helps..

Comment: That doesn't work with an embedded map.  If you combine your answer with the requirement to use the API, then it would apply.

Comment: @geocodezip could you elaborate? i've got it running in an embedded map at the moment, using the api - the only problem which I've just noticed in what I supplied was a typo I had in the onclick (used " instead of ' to wrap the lat/long vals)..